# Ethereum NFT minting successful, but still gives this error

Tags: nft, ethers.js, ethereum-classic, hd-wallets, hdwalletprovider

I am trying to build a Ethereum NFT minting website where the website users can mint NFTs on blockchain without an external wallet (e.g. Metamask).
I asked a question here before and got reply as to how to achieve this.
[How to use one Ethereum account for all NFT minting transactions for website users](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111845/how-to-use-one-ethereum-account-for-all-nft-minting-transactions-for-website-use)

The advice given was that the user can use the hdwallet provider and the Ethers.js library.
This way, the minting fees can be paid from a central Ethereum account.

Now, I have coded the application as follows. The minting works and the transaction is recorded on the Rinkerby test network.

```
    import LocationNFT from '../abis/Location.json'
    let nftAddress = "0x....";
    let privateKey= "0x....";
    let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('rinkeby');
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
    var mainContract = new ethers.Contract(nftAddress, LocationNFT.abi, wallet); 
    const num = mainContract.mintNFT(location).send({ from: fromAddress })  
      .once('receipt', (receipt) => 
      {
             console.log ('num: ', num);
             console.log ('JSON.stringify(num) : ', JSON.stringify(num));
               
      })
```

Location Contract code:
Contains only the following function:

```
    function mintNFT(string memory _location) public returns (uint256) {    
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();    
        require(!_locationExists[_location]);
        uint _id = locations.push(_location);
        _mint(msg.sender, _id);
        _locationExists[_location] = true;
        return newItemId;
    }
```

However, regardless of the successful minting on the Rinkerby test network, I do get the following error which is shown in the console. I would like to resolve this so that I get can get the transaction number ('num' in the above code) which I can show to the user.

**Could anyone help me resolve this error?**

```
    TypeError: mainContract.mintNFT(...).send is not a function
     at App._this.mint (App.js:359)
     at onSubmit (App.js:475)
     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
     at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:265)
     at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:571)
     at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:596)
     at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:695)
     at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:704)
     at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:676)
     at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:844)
     at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:852)
     at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:5030)
     at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21425)
     at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2247)
     at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5110)
     at react-dom.development.js:21482
     at Object.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:255)
     at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21481)
     at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2268)
     at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:5086)
```

Comment: It seems you are using etherjs which uses a different syntax than web3js. It should be `await mainContract.mintNFT(location)`. The other problem in your example is that transactions do not return a value, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call for the details.

Comment: I still want to mint the NFT using an address (fromaddress). That is why I need that part added.

Comment: The syntaxis in etherjs is different. Check their documentation for the differences https://docs.ethers.io/v5/migration/web3/. I think in your case you need to use a signer. If you don't want to learn the syntax probably it will be easier to switch to web3js instead.

Comment: Hi, its absolute necessary that I use Ethers.js and not web3 as I am using a hdwallet instead of metamask. please see why I need this requirement from the linked post in my question.

Comment: I put a link to etherjs documentation on how to migrate from web3. In any case you could use hdwallet with web3. Both work well just use whatever is good for you.